# Font size of PhpStorm so small

Tags: ide, phpstorm, font-size

Just updated PhpStorm and the font size is so tiny.

Can anyone help me make it look normal?

Comment: I had this same problem. I just had to go into the font settings and change it manually. I can't get it the same as I had it before though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by going to Settings (`CTRL+ALT+S`), chose `Editor/Color & Fonts/Font/Primary font/Size` and set the wanted size.